# Expected number of correct guess in a game

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Question is as follow.

There is a bag. In the bag, there are $a$ red cubes and $b$ blue cubes. Assume that she knows exactly how many cubes for each of the colors before the draw.  Mary is going to draw all the cubes one by one out of the bag randomly. For every turn, she will make a guess on the color before drawing the cube. Find the expected number of correct guess in the game.

Trial:
I can solve for a simpler case, that is when she doesn't know the number of cubes of each color. But if she does, then I can figure out her strategy, that is she is going to guess the color which is greater in number in the bag. Also, I tried the find the probability of getting one correct only but cant gets a success because it seems to depend on the previous results.

Comment: Try a recursive solution.  If $G(a,b)$ is the expected number of correct guesses with $a$ red cubes and $b$ blue cubes, you can express $G(a,b)$ in terms of $G(a-1,b)$ and $G(a,b-1)$.  (I haven't actually done this, but I think it's the way to go.)

Comment: Could you give us some context? Do you have reason to believe there's a solution in closed form?

Comment: @joriki This is a question asked by my friend, which get me thinking for like a day. I am not sure if there is a solution in closed form. It seems to me that there must be some way to express the expected number because it is drawing finitely many rounds.

Comment: So the cubes come out at random, but she knows the composition of the bag at the start. Are her guesses random or does she employ a strategy based on her knowledge of the bag’s contents? For example, If the latter is true, then she should be guaranteed to guess the last block correctly.

Comment: @LaarsHelenius yes, her guesses are employing a strategy. I even split 2 cases. Case 1, a>b, in which this will reduce to case 2, a=b because she will just keep picking $a$ until $a=b$, otherwise she will just have exactly $a-b$ correct

Comment: @JamrsTang so in other words, her strategy is to always guess the most prevalent color left in the bag after each draw. And if after a draw the number of each color is equal, her guess doesn’t change from her previous guess.

Answer (score 3):

We find the following recurrence:

$$E(a,b) = \begin{cases}
\frac{bE(a,b-1) + a(E(a-1,b)+1)}{a+b}&\text{if } a\ge b,\\
E(b,a)&\text{if }b>a,\\
0&\text{if }a=b=0.
\end{cases}$$

These cases are pretty obvious: the first says "we gain one point if we guess right", the second says "we can pick the cube that is more common and it doesn't matter which that is", and the third says "you can't score any points on an empty bag"

From here we can begin to find easy ones: It's clear that $E(a,0) = a$, for instance.  But it gets harder from there - each entry depends on the ones before it in ugly ways.  I present here the values for $a,b \le 5$.

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\ &0&1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2&3&4&5\\
1&1&1\frac{1}{2}&2\frac{1}{3}&3\frac{1}{4}&4\frac{1}{5}&5\frac{1}{6}\\
2&2&2\frac{1}{3}&2\frac{5}{6}&3\frac{3}{5}&4\frac{7}{15}&5\frac{8}{21}\\
3&3&3\frac{1}{4}&3\frac{3}{5}&4\frac{1}{10}&4\frac{29}{35}&5\frac{37}{56}\\
4&4&4\frac{1}{5}&4\frac{7}{15}&4\frac{29}{35}&5\frac{23}{70}&6\frac{2}{63}\\
5&5&5\frac{1}{6}&5\frac{8}{21}&5\frac{37}{56}&6\frac{2}{63}&6\frac{67}{126}
\end{array}$$

From this a few other closed forms for special cases are apparent:

- for $(1,n)$, it's $n+\frac{1}{n+1}$
- for $(2,n)$ with $n>0$, it's $n+\frac{2(n+3)}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

There are sure to be others but I don't know them.

Comment: The small denominators are surprising; together with the closed forms you found they might indicate that there's more hope for an overall closed form than I thought.

Comment: Looks like we can actually use $\binom{a}{a+b}$ as the denominators.  Let's see what we get when we multiply that in...

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense, as there are only that many inequivalent drawing sequences, so it's a matter of counting the successful ones. Perhaps OEIS can help, then. (I take it you meant $\binom{a+b}a$.)

Comment: Looks like OEIS doesn't know this one in full.  Interestingly, the diagonal and just-off-diagonal ones *are* there: http://oeis.org/A014314 "number of up steps in all length n left factors of Dyck paths" (and yes that's what I meant)

Comment: @DanUznanski You can think of taking a black one as going down and taking a red one going up. Hence if there are equal amount, you end up on the same level. I think the connection to Dyck paths comes from that.

Comment: It looks like your formula for $E(2,n)$ is not valid for $n=1$  I get $2+\frac43.$  You must have to restrict it to $n\ge2$

Comment: Careful, n here is 1, so it's 1+4/3

Comment: @DanUznanski Right you are, my bad.   I'm computing the formula for the $(3,n)$ case, and I thought I'd found the error in my computations, but no such luck.

Comment: The reason you couldn't find a formula for the $a=3$ case is that it only holds for $b\ge3$.  I've posted an answer with the formula.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete rewrite of my earlier answer, because I can now compute a very good approximation to $E(n,k)$.$$\boxed{E(n,k) = n+\frac{k}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right), \text{ for }n\ge k}$$

Here's the proof.
$\newcommand{\#}[1]{^{\overline{#1}}}$
Let $E(n,k)$ be the expected number of correct guesses, if there are $n$ red cubes and $k$ blue cubes, and $n\ge k.$  We know that $E(n,0)=n.$  I claim that $E$ is of the form $$
E(n,k)=n+\frac{p_k(n)}{(n+1)\#k},\text{ if }n\ge k\ge1,$$ where $n\#k$ is the rising factorial function, $n\#k=n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k-1),$ and $p_k$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ with integer coefficients and leading coefficient $k$.

When $k=1,n\ge 1,$ we have$$
E(n,1)=\frac{n}{n+1}(1+E(n-1,1))+\frac{1}{n+1}n\\
(n+1)E(n,1)=2n+nE(n-1,1)\\
(n+1)E(n,1)-nE(n-1,1)=2n\\
(n+1)E(n,1)-E(0,1)=\sum_{m=1}^n((m+1)E(m,1)-E(m-1,1))=\sum_{m=1}^n2m=n(n+1),
$$ 
and since $E(0,1)=1,$ we have $$E(n,1)=n+\frac{1}{n+1}\implies p_1(n)=1$$

Now suppose that $k>1$ and that the theorem is true for $k-1$.

When $n\ge k,$ we have $$
E(n,k)=\frac{n}{n+k}(1+E(n-1,k))+\frac{k}{n+k}E(n,k-1)\\
(n+k)E(n,k)=n+nE(n-1,k)+k\left(n+\frac{p_{k-1}(n)}{(n+1)\#{k-1}}\right)\\
(n+1)\#kE(n,k)=n\#kE(n-1,k)+(k+1)n\#k+kp_{k-1}(n)$$
$$
(n+1)\#kE(n,k)-k\#kE(k-1,k)=\sum_{m=k}^n(k+1)m\#k+k\sum_{m=k}^np_{k-1}(m)\tag1
$$
Now, $$E(k-1,k)=E(k,k-1)=k+\frac{p_{k-1}(k)}{(k+1)\#{k-1}}\\
k\#kE(k-1,k)=k\cdot k\#k+\frac{k\#kp_{k-1}(k)}{(k+1)\#{k-1}}=k\cdot k\#k+kp_{k-1}(k)
$$
Furthermore, we have $$
\sum_{m=k}^n(k+1)m\#k=\sum_{m=k}^n\left(m\#{k+1}-(m-1)\#{k+1}\right)=n\#{k+1}-(k-1)\#{k+1},
$$so that $(1)$ becomes$$
(n+1)\#kE(n,k)=k\cdot k\#k+kp_{k-1}(k)+n\#{k+1}-(k-1)\#{k+1}+k\sum_{m=k}^np_{k-1}(m)\\
E(n,k)=n + \frac{1}{(n+1)\#k}\left(k\#k+kp_{k-1}(k)+k\sum_{m=k}^np_{k-1}(m)\right),
$$and we have $$
p_k(n)=k\#k+kp_{k-1}(k)+k\sum_{m=k}^np_{k-1}(m),
$$
which by the induction hypothesis, is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ with integer coefficients.

By the induction hypothesis,
$$p_{k-1}=(k-1)n\#{k-2}+f,$$ where f is a polynomial of degree less than $k-2,$ so by the same difference formula we used earlier,  $\sum_{m=k}^np_{k-1}(m)$ has leading coefficient $1,$ and $p_k$ has leading coefficient $k.$

It follows that $$\boxed{E(n,k) = n+\frac{k}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right), \text{ for }n\ge k}$$

I wasn't able to find a closed form for $p_k.$  Here are the formulas for $0\le k\le9.$

$$0 \\
1 \\
2 n + 6 \\
3 n^{2} + 21 n + 42 \\
4 n^{3} + 48 n^{2} + 212 n + 360 \\
5 n^{4} + 90 n^{3} + 655 n^{2} + 2370 n + 3720 \\
6 n^{5} + 150 n^{4} + 1590 n^{3} + 9210 n^{2} + 30084 n + 45360 \\
7 n^{6} + 231 n^{5} + 3325 n^{4} + 27405 n^{3} + 140308 n^{2} + 433524 n + 640080 \\
8 n^{7} + 336 n^{6} + 6272 n^{5} + 68880 n^{4} + 492632 n^{3} + 2349984 n^{2} + 7040928 n + 10281600 \\
9 n^{8} + 468 n^{7} + 10962 n^{6} + 153720 n^{5} + 1441881 n^{4} + 9472932 n^{3} + 43362828 n^{2} + 127722960 n + 185431680 \\$$

These were produced by this sympy script:

```
from fractions import Fraction
from sympy.abc import m,n
from sympy import Sum, Poly, latex
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.factorials import RisingFactorial as rise

'''
Let E(n,k) be the expected number of correct guesses, where n >= k.  I claim that E(n,k) is of the form

E(n,k) = n + p[k](n)/rise(n+1,k)

where rise(n+1,k) is the rising factorial (n+1)(n+2)...(n+k) and p[k] is a polynomial of degree k-1.  The purpose of this
program is to compute p[k] for some small values of k.
'''
p = []                 # list of polynmials
p.append(Poly(0,n).as_expr())       
for k in range(1, 10):
    f = p[k-1]
    g=rise(k,k)+k*f.subs(n,k)+k*Sum(f,(n,k,n)).doit()
    p.append(g)
for f in p: print(latex(f.expand()),'\\\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let $m_{a,b} = \mathbb{E}[\text{number of correct guesses when there are }a, b \text { (red, blues)}]$.

We know $m_{0,k} = m_{k,0} = k$, for all $k\geq0$, since Mary will always guess correct when just one color.

Then for positive $a$ and $b$ we have the recursion

$$m_{a,b} = \begin{cases}
\frac{a}{a+b}(m_{a-1,b}+1) + \frac{b}{a+b}m_{a,b-1} \space \space \text{  if } a\geq b \\ 
\frac{b}{a+b}(m_{a,b-1}+1) + \frac{a}{a+b}m_{a-1,b} \space \space \text{  if } a < b 
\end{cases}$$

which comes from the fact that Mary will guess the next cube correctly with probability $\frac{\max(a,b)}{a+b}$ (and get $1$ cube) in addition to the rest cubes, whose expectation is $m_{*,*}$ where the subscripts depend on which color cube the drawn was.

Comment: Note that if Mary guesses wrong, the game moves to a different state than if she guesses right. Regardless of $a, b$, the value $m_{a, b}$ depends on both $m_{a-1, b}$ and $m_{a, b-1}$.

Comment: You need $m_{a, b} = \tfrac{a}{a + b}(m_{a-1, b} + 1) + \tfrac{b}{a + b}m_{a, b-1}$ when $a \geq b$, and symmetrically when $b < a$. But I assume that OP is looking for something closed form?

Answer (score 0):

Non-recursive formula: the correct number of guesses $C(a, b) = C_1 + \cdots + C_{a+b}$, where $C_k = 1$ iff the $k$th guess was correct, and $C_k = 0$ otherwise. Hence
$$\mathbb{E}(C(a,b)) = \mathbb{E}(C_1 + \cdots + C_{a + b}) = \mathbb{E}(C_1) + \cdots + \mathbb{E}(C_{a + b}) = \mathbb{P}(C_1 = 1) + \cdots + \mathbb{P}(C_{a + b} = 1).$$
We have, for example,
$$\mathbb{P}(C_1 = 1) = \frac{\max(a, b)}{a + b},$$
and in general
$$\mathbb{P}(C_{k + 1} = 1) = \sum_{r = \max(0, k - b)}^{\min(a, k)} \mathbb{P}(C_{k + 1} = 1 \mid r \text{ reds in draws } 1, \dots, k) \mathbb{P}(r \text{ reds in draws } 1, \dots, k).$$
We can calculate the first, conditional, probability assuming the strategy that Mary always guesses whichever colour is most common in the bag:
$$\mathbb{P}(C_{k + 1} = 1 \mid r \text{ reds drawn in draws } 1, \dots, k) = \frac{\max(a - r, b - (k - r))}{a + b-k}.$$
We can also calculate the second, unconditional, probability using the fact that this is a draw from the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Definition):
$$\mathbb{P}(r \text{ reds drawn in draws } 1, \dots, k) = \frac{\binom{a}{r}\binom{b}{k - r}}{\binom{a + b}{k}}.$$
So we have
$$\mathbb{P}(C_{k + 1} = 1) = \sum_{r = \max(0, k - b)}^{\min(a, k)}\frac{\max(a - r, b - (k - r))}{a + b-k}\frac{\binom{a}{r}\binom{b}{k - r}}{\binom{a + b}{k}}.$$
Hence
$$\mathbb{E}(C(a, b)) = \sum_{k = 0}^{a + b - 1} \sum_{r = \max(0, k - b)}^{\min(a, k)}\frac{\max(a - r, b - (k - r))}{a + b-k}\frac{\binom{a}{r}\binom{b}{k - r}}{\binom{a + b}{k}}.$$